# implement python split on individual columnar values of a csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing a script to process some csv data I have in order to render it on a d3.js map, I'm providing the full script immediately after this sentence, but just for context, the important part of my question is below.

```
# The purpose of this script is the refinement of the job data attained from the
# JSI as it is rendered by the `csv generator` contributed by Luis for purposes
# of presentation on the dashboard map. 

import csv

# The number of columns
num_headers = 9

# Remove invalid characters from records
def url_escaper(data):
  for line in data:
    yield line.replace('&','&amp;')

# Be sure to configure input & output files
with open("input.txt", 'r') as file_in, open("try_this_output.txt", 'w') as file_out:
    csv_in = csv.reader( url_escaper( file_in ) )
    csv_out = csv.writer(file_out)

    # Get rid of rows that have the wrong number of columns
    # and rows that have only whitespace for a columnar value
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_in, start=1):
        for e in row:
            if "|" in e:
                e = e.split(";")[0]
        if not [e for e in row if not e.strip()]:
            if len(row) == num_headers:
                csv_out.writerow(row)
        else:
            print "line %d is malformed" % i
```

There are some columnar values that are structured as so:

```
linux|devops|firewall|vmware|.net-framework|.net|paas
```

I want to slice them up using the following snippet:

```
e.split("|")[0]
```

such that I'm left only with the first part of text before the "`|`", i.e. in the above example `linux`.

I need to write this processed data to an output file.

I know that the snippet works, but I can't figure out how to fit that in with my pipeline.

This is the part that concerns me:

```
for i, row in enumerate(csv_in, start=1):
    for e in row:
        if "|" in e:
            e = e.split("|")[0]
    if not [e for e in row if not e.strip()]:
        if len(row) == num_headers:
            csv_out.writerow(row)
    else:
        print "line %d is malformed" % i
```

Particularly this:

```
    for e in row:
        if "|" in e:
            e = e.split(";")[0]
```

It's clear that isn't the way to achieve this aim.

An example of the input data is this:

```
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiMjk1MzYyMDY2IiwicyI6ImhiTUN6MTdUUkVPdWl5NUI2bDdwQXcifQ.A6MlT_WKpLx763hZe44X4pQ0KOMHYuITosCIwuMbPxM,Technical Account Manager, Technical Delivery Manager - Cloud,Peopleworks,Farnborough,51.293999,-0.754624,United Kingdom,linux|devops|firewall|vmware|.net-framework|.net|paas,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiMzA5MzE5OTExIiwicyI6Ik9feVBUT1VNVC0tcUZ2N1FvRWNVU1EifQ.C8ZAc9RAFSMdyaCaIIMB51-jGS01Az29VY8Dblc7QM4,Management Consultant - Utilities Smart Energy,Capgemini Consulting,Lee,51.451818,-0.02806,United Kingdom,leadership|database|project management|design|scada,1
```

and the ideal output would be

```
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiMjk1MzYyMDY2IiwicyI6ImhiTUN6MTdUUkVPdWl5NUI2bDdwQXcifQ.A6MlT_WKpLx763hZe44X4pQ0KOMHYuITosCIwuMbPxM,Technical Account Manager, Technical Delivery Manager - Cloud,Peopleworks,Farnborough,51.293999,-0.754624,United Kingdom,linux,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiMzA5MzE5OTExIiwicyI6Ik9feVBUT1VNVC0tcUZ2N1FvRWNVU1EifQ.C8ZAc9RAFSMdyaCaIIMB51-jGS01Az29VY8Dblc7QM4,Management Consultant - Utilities Smart Energy,Capgemini Consulting,Lee,51.451818,-0.02806,United Kingdom,leadership,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve the problem using regular expressions.

I grabbed your input data and put it in a file 'input.txt'

```
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiMjk1MzYyMDY2IiwicyI6ImhiTUN6MTdUUkVPdWl5NUI2bDdwQXcifQ.A6MlT_WKpLx763hZe44X4pQ0KOMHYuITosCIwuMbPxM,Technical Account Manager, Technical Delivery Manager - Cloud,Peopleworks,Farnborough,51.293999,-0.754624,United Kingdom,linux|devops|firewall|vmware|.net-framework|.net|paas,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiMzA5MzE5OTExIiwicyI6Ik9feVBUT1VNVC0tcUZ2N1FvRWNVU1EifQ.C8ZAc9RAFSMdyaCaIIMB51-jGS01Az29VY8Dblc7QM4,Management Consultant - Utilities Smart Energy,Capgemini Consulting,Lee,51.451818,-0.02806,United Kingdom,leadership|database|project management|design|scada,1
```

Your expected result:

```
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiMjk1MzYyMDY2IiwicyI6ImhiTUN6MTdUUkVPdWl5NUI2bDdwQXcifQ.A6MlT_WKpLx763hZe44X4pQ0KOMHYuITosCIwuMbPxM,Technical Account Manager, Technical Delivery Manager - Cloud,Peopleworks,Farnborough,51.293999,-0.754624,United Kingdom,linux,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiMzA5MzE5OTExIiwicyI6Ik9feVBUT1VNVC0tcUZ2N1FvRWNVU1EifQ.C8ZAc9RAFSMdyaCaIIMB51-jGS01Az29VY8Dblc7QM4,Management Consultant - Utilities Smart Energy,Capgemini Consulting,Lee,51.451818,-0.02806,United Kingdom,leadership,1
```

Here's the code I used:

```
import re

src = open('input.txt')
output = open('output.txt', 'w')


pat = r'([^,]*\|[^,]*)'

for line in src:
    the_search = re.search(pat, line) # Search the line for something containing '|'
    if the_search:
        the_group = the_search.group(0) # Grab the capture group
        value = the_group.split("|")[0] # Grab the first item after splitting based on '|'
        new_line = re.sub(pat, value, line) # Use re.sub to replace that entire pattern with the value
        output.write(new_line)

src.close()
output.close()
```

You'll need to tailor this solution to fit what you're trying to do, but the regex should work.